# How to declare an object in the scope of a function?

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

I'm in assignment 2 of Stanford CS193p (on iTunes U) and I got confused by an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

In the first assignment, we used something like this:

```
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    //...
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.display.text = resultString;
}
```

This worked fine. Now, I am trying something similar with `NSSet`:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program{
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    NSSet *listOfFunctions = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"cos", @"sin", @"sqrt", "π", @"tan", @"neg", @"^", @"rad", @"+", @"-", @"/", @"*", nil];
    //...
}
```

This crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the `*listOfFunctions` line when the function is run. My question is this: Why does the first example work and make an NSString from the `+ stringWithFormat:` function while the second example doesn't make an NSSet? Do I need to do something with `[[NSSet alloc] init]`? I've attempted also with NSSet's `+ initWithObjects:`, with no luck.

Comment: Let me see which option to choose instead of "too localized"...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing at-sign. Belongs to typewriting.stackexchange.com. (Seriously, this **is** too localized.)


Comment: I've seen other questions with this exact same issue - a C-string where an `NSString` was expected. If others are having the same problem is it really too localized? Granted, the others are probably impossible to find via search.

Comment: @rmaddy It's a simple typo question, hence it is.

Comment: @rmaddy (Furthermore, it's also a simple "I couldn't be bothered opening the debugger" question, so it's an even better fit for now-obsolescent "too localized".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the strings in your set is a C-string, not an `NSString`.

In other words, you forgot the `@` before the `"π"` string.

Comment: Yep, I can't accept this as an answer yet. This _is_ what I would call "too localized". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
"π"
```

You forgot the `@` symbol in front of this string, which makes it a C string instead of an NSString. Use `@"π"` instead.